# Combining Polly policies and accessing handled exception in Polly policy Fallback

Tags: f#, fallback, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

Given the following F# snippets

```
//User Code
.. code that can throw exceptions
"Success"
```

#### P1 policy

```
Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(fun cx -> cx.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryForever((fun _ cx _ -> (cx :?> CosmosException).RetryAfter.Value), (fun _ _ _ _ -> ()))
```

#### P2 policy

```
Policy<string>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Fallback("Failure")
```

#### P3 Policy

```
Policy<string>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Fallback(fun ex -> ex.Message)
```

#### Question #1 - How to combine P1 and P2?

Combine P1 and P2 in a policy P so that:

- if User Code succeeds, "Success" is returned to the caller
- if User Code throws CosmosException, P retries forever using the returned RetryAfter TimeSpan
- if User Code throws any other exception, "Failure" is returned to the caller

#### Question # 2 - How to write P3?

There doesn't seem to be a Fallback overload that allows to access the handled exception to use it when constructing the fallback return value

Final scope is to combine P1 and P3 to obtain a policy PFinal such that:

- if User Code succeeds, "Success" is returned to the caller
- if User Code throws CosmosException, PFinal retries forever using the returned RetryAfter TimeSpan
- if User Code throws any other exception, the handled exception message is returned to the caller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer to question 1

In order to be able to chain policies you need to define them as compatible policies. Your `p2` returns a `string` whereas your `p1` returns nothing. So, you need to change `p1` to return with `string` as well. Then you can use [`Policy.Wrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) to define chaining, [escalation](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc).

I'm not an F# developer so I will present the solution in C#. But the idea is the same in both languages:

```cs
var p1 = Policy<string>
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryForever(sleepDurationProvider: (_, dr, __) => ((CosmosException)dr.Exception).RetryAfter.Value,
                        onRetry: (_, __, ___) => { });
var p2 = Policy<string>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Fallback("Failure");

var p = Policy.Wrap(p1, p2);
```

- Please note that we have to change `Policy` to `Policy<string>` in `p1`
- Also note that the `sleepDurationProvider` will not receive the `Exception` as a parameter

  - Rather it will receive a [`DelegateResult<string>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/DelegateResult.cs) which have two mutually exclusive properties: `Exception` and `Result`

#### Answer to question 2

- There is an overload, where the `fallbackAction` delegate receives a `DelegateResult<string>` as a parameter

```cs
var p2 = Policy<string>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Fallback(fallbackAction: (dr, _, __) => dr.Exception.Message,
              onFallback: (_, __) => { });
```

---

**Update #1**: Providing clarity

Changing the `p1` definition from `Policy` to `Policy<string>` has another implication as well: Your to be decorated code should return a string (namely "Success")

Before the change:

```cs
//user code

//to be decorated code which might throw exception

return "Success";
```

After the change:

```cs
//user code

//The decorated code either return "Success" or throws CosmosException 
return combinedPolicy.Execute(...
```

---

**Update #2**: Fix ordering

I suggested to chain the `p1` and `p2` with `Policy.Wrap`. Unfortunately I have showed you the wrong order `Policy.Wrap(p1, p2)`. The **correct one** is `Policy.Wrap(p2, p1)` since the right most parameter is the most inner and the left most is the most outer. So, in your case the retry is the inner and the fallback is the outer.

Apologise for the inconvenience.